# Python : pickle.load() only returns the first value of the file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm creating a very basic program that stores a dictionary of words translated from English to French, for example :

I'm storing all those values in a file that I append and read using the pickle function.

The problem is that when I use pickle.load to read the file and then print it, only the first value is returned.

I can't see where is my error, and I've been looking everywhere without getting any answer. 
Thanks in advance.

```
import pickle
import os

clear=lambda:os.system("cls")

def pause():
    input("Press ENTER to continue.")

def print_dictionary(dct):
    print("Dictionary (English / French)")
    for wordenglish, wordfrench in dct.items():
        print("{} : {}".format(wordenglish, wordfrench))

dictionary={}
for loop in range(3):
    wordEnglish=input("Enter the word in English : ")
    wordFrench=input("Enter the word in French : ")
    pause()
    clear()
    print("Saving ...")
    dictionary[wordEnglish]=wordFrench
    with open("data","ab") as file:
        pickler=pickle.Pickler(file)
        pickler.dump(dictionary)
    print("Saved !")
pause()
with open("data","rb") as file:
    unpickler=pickle.Unpickler(file)
    dictionary_get=unpickler.load()
print_dictionary(dictionary_get)
pause()
```

For example, if I enter "Fire","Feu" / "Water","Eau" / "Mud","Boue", the only value I will get will be "Fire","Feu".

Comment: Because you save each item separately inside the loop, overwriting the pickle file each time.

Comment: @DanielRoseman no they are using 'ab' mode. The problem is that `.load` won't keep trying to load once it deserializes an object. You have to keep calling `.load`

Comment: However, why are you progressively dumping incremental versions of your dict?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, because when I open the data file I can clearly see all the values are here.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep calling .load" ? @juanpa.arrivillaga
As for dumping incremental versions of my dict, it's just because I don't know any other way to do this ...

Comment: each time you call `unpickler.load()` it will load one object and stop. If there is another object and you call load, it will load it. Just use [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) though, it's exactly what you want. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Then how may I use `shelve` in my code ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Read the documentation for various examples, it tells you all you need

Answer (score 1):

use exception like

```
try:
   while True:
      y=pickle.load(file)
      print(y)
except EOFError:
   print('End of File')
```

Comment: You should review your code formatting to make it readable, especially in Python where indentation is key!

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the **walrus operator** (**:=**) in a clear way:

```
with open('pickle_file_to_read.p', 'rb') as f:
    pickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
    while record := pickler.load():
        # record is the read object from the pickle file.
```